# Linux bash tool for showing folder structure on both sides

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line-tool

I passed by a Linux command-line tool for displaying and easily navigating the files/folders on a GUI-like user interface some time ago, but I can't remember the name of the command.

The background color was blue (like the edit tool in Windows Command Prompt) and it was easy to navigate between files and move/copy them, and even edit them.

Is it a builtin tool for all Linux/Unix systems, or does any specific version of Linux support the tool?

Comment: https://www.midnight-commander.org/

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Not general Linux usage. To your question. Perhaps [Midnight Commander](https://www.midnight-commander.org/)?

Comment: @AlanAu Well, I kind of knew that my question could be accepted as inappropriate in this site, but I didn't know a better place that I was more sure to be answered. I got the answer anyway and a lesson of getting 3 downvotes too :)

Comment: @technophyle - don't worry about the downvoters. Some people are very strict ... untill they need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try **Midnight Commander** ?
From your description it looks like it might fit the bill.